Snowflake join using between =incorrect values
I am using Snowflake, joining two tables using zip codes.
One table has a zip code , other has a value linked to zip code from - zip code to combination.
Zip codes go from all numbers to numbers and letters.
In SQL server the join works and returns 1 expected result.
SHIP_TO_ZIP   ZIP_CODE_FROM   ZIP_CODE_TO LEADTIME
40136   40121   40141   2
In Snowflake the same zip code returns multiple records
SHIP_TO_ZIP   ZIP_CODE_FROM   ZIP_CODE_TO LEADTIME
40136   10  79  3
40136   40121   40141   2
40136   4010    4029    4
Any idea why and how to correct this?
Dont know why in SQL server it works and in Snowflake i am having multiple records on the join
SELECT DISTINCT RR.SHIP_TO_ZIP, LT.ZIP_CODE_FROM, LT.ZIP_CODE_TO, LT.LEADTIME 
FROM
CARR RR LEFT JOIN AGREEMENTS  LT 
WHERE RR.COUNTRY = LT.COUNTRY 
AND RR.SHIP_TO_ZIP BETWEEN LT.POSTCODE AND LT.POSTCODE_TO 

Thank you in advance
SOURCE DATA
CARR TABLE



ship_to_zip
COUNTRY




40136
IT



AGREEMENTS TABLE



ZIP_CODE_FROM
ZIP_CODE_TO
COUNTRY
LEADTIME




10
79
IT
3


4010
4029
IT
4


40121
40141
IT
2



EXPECTED RESULT



SHIP_TO_ZIP
ZIP_CODE_FROM
ZIP_CODE_TO
LEADTIME




40136
40121
40141
2



ACTUAL RESULT



SHIP_TO_ZIP
ZIP_CODE_FROM
ZIP_CODE_TO
LEADTIME




40136
10
79
3


40136
4010
4029
4


40136
40121
40141
2



I managed workaround, where i cast in number the numerical ship_to_zip in a subquery and then join all the numerical and alphanumerical zips, but it is not eficient.

Please don't link to images. Add all relevant information to your question as editable text, appropriately formatted

Are both databases using the same collation?  Database collation is a set of rules that control how characters are sorted and compared in a database management system. It affects how data is stored and retrieved, particularly string values

Also, please update your question with sample data for your source tables, the result you expect to achieve and the SQL code you are running

Are the datatypes for the columns identical in both systems?

all columns Varchar

Can you also update your question with the source data for the two tables, just for that zip code? It only needs to include the columns used in your SQL statement

I can't imagine why this would work in sql server. These are varchar and will be sorted/compared lexicographically, not numerically. Cast your columns to numeric in the SQL or in the table for this logic to work properly.

Here is a dbfiddle of this not working the way you would lik in sql server. As suspected, sql server also uses a lexicographical ordering for this logic (how could it not?).
